# Uniswap v2/v3 - calculate pool liquidity

Tags: ethereum, uniswap

I'm working on a routine to find the most liquid pool across Uniswap v2 and v3. Therefore I like to compare the pool's liquidity, but I'm not sure how to do so on a Uniswap v3 pool. Some help would be highly appreciated.

**Uniswap v2**

`Math.sqrt(reserve0, reserve1)`

**Uniswap v3**

??? call liquidity() function of pool?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, reading the `liquidity` from on-chain data is one way, and this number will be comparable with what you have for v2, because in both versions liquidity "[can be thought of as the amount that token1 reserves (either actual or virtual) changes for a given change in √P](https://uniswap.org/whitepaper-v3.pdf)".

But liquidity is more tricky in Uniswap v3 because it's (1) concentrated and (2) not uniform.

For one, in v2 the liquidity of a pool and the liquidity of a position are conceptually the same, the `L = sqrt(x*y)` formula works for both.

In Uniswap v3, the liquidity of a position is still computed by `L = sqrt(x*y)`, but `x` and `y` here are virtual assets. They correspond to the real assets in the positions via equations

x = (x_real + L/√p_a), and

y = (y_real + L*√p_b)

The liquidity of a position is uniform in the range `[p_a, p_b]`, and zero for prices outside of this range.

The liquidity of a v3 pool is defined the sum of the liquidities of all active (in-range) positions in the pool. It's convenient to get it from the chain, rather than to compute it yourself!

However, a swap can cause the pool to enter other tick ranges, so that some positions get kicked out of the range during a swap. This will change the pool's liquidity and price impact during the swap. See the Algorithm 4 from the whitepaper. It means that for accurate results it's also needed to track the liquidities of the close-to-price but inactive tick ranges.

Comment: thanks for your detailed feedback. Sounds very trick to get the v3 liquidity. What’s your recommendation to compare the v2 and v3 liquidity for one pair like PEPE/WETH?

Comment: @MrCoinSiX if you don't want to make large swaps (like for trading in size or sandwich attacks) then looking at the `pool.liquidity()` value should be fine. try it out in practice

Comment: thx, already tried. But when I use getReserves() for Uniswap v2 and calculate liquidity with sqrt(x*y) and compare it to liquidity() from Uniswap v3 the result gives a false signal. I mean the bigger value doesn’t always represent the pool with the greater liquidity

Answer (score 1):

This is the formula I found in [UniswapV3 documentation](https://uniswapv3book.com/docs/milestone_1/calculating-liquidity/). It seems like for Uniswap V3, additional parameters of upper bound, current, lower bound prices are needed to calculate liquidity.

```
q96 = 2**96

def price_to_sqrtp(p):
    return int(math.sqrt(p) * q96)

sqrtp_low = price_to_sqrtp(price_lower_bound)
sqrtp_cur = price_to_sqrtp(price_current)
sqrtp_upp = price_to_sqrtp(price_upper_bound)

def liquidity0(amount, pa, pb):
    return (amount * (pa * pb) / q96) / abs(pb - pa)

def liquidity1(amount, pa, pb):
    return amount * q96 / abs(pb - pa)

liq0 = liquidity0(reserve0, sqrtp_cur, sqrtp_upp)
liq1 = liquidity1(reserve1, sqrtp_cur, sqrtp_low)
liquidity = int(min(liq0, liq1))
```

Comment: thx, but the mentioned article is related to adding liquidity to a pool. Not what I looking for

Answer (score 0):

I ended up by calling balanceOf() for token0 and token1 for Uniswap v3 pools. Not the best solution, but the only one I came up with.